# Process each line separately in selected text

Tags: c#, envdte

I'm trying to select a set of lines and process each line separately in a text document using **c#** language. How can i get separate lines to process? 
I tried these codes and got struck. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
EnvDTE.DTE dte = MyPackage.MyPackagePackage.GetGlobalService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
EnvDTE.TextSelection text = (dte.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection);
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you are reading from a text file this code will help you:

```
string fileToRead = "D:\\temp.txt";    // Temp.txt is the file to read

if (File.Exists(fileToRead))
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileToRead);
    do
    {
         textBox1.Text += reader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";    // Read each line and pass it to the TextBox1

    } while (reader.Peek() != -1);
    reader.Close(); // Close the file 
}
```

Comment: Hello Pabinator, My problem is i dont use text document. I have to process on the selected text in a document. I can get that selected lines from TextSelection class. When i pass this selected text to a stream reader it doesnt work as expected

Comment: How does this reply relates to EnvDTE? This cannot be an answer!

Answer (score 2):

TextSelection interface has got Text property which you can use as string in C#. Further you can split the string to retrieve the lines.

Alternatively TextSelection interface has additional property called TextRanges which has numeric indexers  to access each line.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at text properties. What should i do to reflect my changes in the selected text itself?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.editpoint.gettext.aspx) form MSDN.

You can use Startpoint and EndPoint for your job.

Also this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.textpoint.aspx) link might be useful to Loop through all the lines from your selection.